# d3 - Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Tags: php, d3.js

I am working with a scatter plot in d3. I am successfully connected to my database with the php script below but when I run my d3 code I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
```

On the connection call to the php script in my d3 code:

```
d3.json("connection.php", function(error, data){
if (error) throw error;
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d['TITLE'] = d.TITLE.toString();
    d['YEAR'] = +d['YEAR'];
    d['counter'] = +d['counter'];
    console.log(data.query1Results);
    console.log(data.query2Results);
    })
```

Here is my php script:

```
<?php
$username = "xxx"; 
$password = "";   
$host = "xxxx";
$database="xxxx";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$data = array(
'query1Results' => array(),
'query2Results' => array()
);

$myquery = "SELECT  `ID`, `TITLE`, `YEAR`, `In_library` FROM  `papers` where In_library = 1";

$query1 = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query1 ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query1); $x++) {
    $data['query1Results'][] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
}

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `ID_to`, count(*) as `counter` from `citations` group by `ID_to` DESC");

if ( ! $query2 ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query2); $x++) {
    $data['query2Results'][] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);


?>
```

Would be very grateful if anyone could tell me what is causing this error and possible solutions as I cant see where I have gone wrong (probably because I have been looking at is for so long!) thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Could you post an example of the JSON data please?

Comment: Do you mean the data from my database  ? @

Comment: Whatever you're passing to the Javascript. I assume you've checked for errors when loading the JSON?

Comment: You didn't follow my advice in your last question.  `data.forEach` --> data here is an object, not an array anymore.  `data.query1Results` is a array of your first query, `data.query2Results` is the array results of your second query.

Comment: I have completely confused myself.. so is it meant to be `data.query1Results (function(d) { ....` and where do I use `data.forEach` if anywhere @Mark

Comment: @Mark `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query1Results' of undefined` thats the error I am getting now when I use use data.query1Results instead of data.forEach.. But I dont know if that was what I should have done. I'm very sorry I'm so new to this that it takes me time to fill in the gaps and appreciate your help alot.

Comment: You should be using `data.query1Results.forEach(function(d){...`  data is a JavaScript object, with two properties, query1Results and query2Results.  Those are arrays and arrays have a method named `forEach` which iterates the array with a callback function.  What does `console.log(data)` should you in the console window?

Comment: @Mark okay sorry about that, `Object {query1Results: Array[3], query2Results: Array[18]}` is what I am getting in the window now and the axis of the graph are now displayed but no dots.

Comment: @Mark Ok so when I do `console.log(data.query1Results)` I get `[Object, Object, Object]0: Object 1: Object` And then it shows the data in the console. and the same with query2Results.. But there are no dots on the graph..

Comment: Sounds like to me that some place in your JavaScript, you are still using `data`, remember your `data` is now composed into two pieces, one for each query.  Look at where you draw the "dots" (circles), you are probably doing `.data(data)`, this should be `.data(data.query2Results)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103889/discussion-between-john-power-and-mark).